# How to use inbulit django templatetags in google-app-engine

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

I am trying to use Django in built templatetags like markup and
humanize in my google app , but its not working.
I added markup and humanize in the INSTALLED_APPS. Still not working.
How to use that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it for humanize, others should be similar. At the end of the controller that invokes your template there is a function that looks like:

```
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Add the following two lines just after def main():

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
template.register_template_library(
             'django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize')
```

No need to add {% load humanize %} in your template.

Thanks to this posting http://blog.yjl.im/2011/02/few-things-on-google-app-engine-i.html that hinted the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this, but you'll need to provide more information before your particular situation can be addressed.  It sounds like there might be an exception that is being thrown--is this the case?  If there is one, what is being printed out to the console (or the log)?

I'm using app-engine-patch and have been able to use both django.contrib.humanize and django.contrib.markup, so you might see if this works for you.