# Getting django's humanize working on App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to add commas to floats for display to end users of my application on GAE. The numbers come from json and are part of a 10 item query with 2 times each (aka 20 numbers per page view). For eg.

```
"total_reach": 276160.0, "total_reach": 500160.0
```

I'm using the python GAE SDK 1.7.3 template system and simply want to display the numbers to the end user with commas e.g.: 276,160 and 500,160. Note, I am using the default webbapp2 and standard templates (from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template) which, as I understand it, is based on Django.

The Django floatformat works great to get rid of the decimal, but now I need to add the comma. Django's humanize looks perfect with its intcomma filter. However, I simply can't figure out how to enable it. I suspect its crazy simple and I'm being dense (and am noob to python) - but I'm out of ideas.

While I tried a range of things, the most recent and promising was (based on my understanding of [the source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/lib/django/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py?r=41)):

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.template import register_template_library
register_template_library('django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize')
```

which gave me the following 500:

```
No module named django.contrib.humanize.templatetags
```

but it seems to be there in the source.

I'm very much at a loss. I've searched around and found items like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901121/how-to-use-inbulit-django-templatetags-in-google-app-engine) which just didn't work and seemed to be aimed at webapp (as opposed to webapp2). Help and thanks!

UPDATE:

Couldn't get it going using the settings.py approach. In the end, I solved it on my own. See below for my functional but not ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get it going using the settings.py approach. In the end I used a [variant of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091596/how-do-i-register-custom-filter-in-google-app-engine-template-system). I replicated the [source code from here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/lib/django/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py?r=34), and replaced the various Django imports at the top of the humanize.py file with

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

register = webapp.template.create_template_register()
```

I then added to my main.py:

```
template.register_template_library('tags.humanize')
```

Then in the template, I just added the filters as expected (e.g. item.count|intcomma). I'm betting this is not a 'best practice', but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't add `django.contrib.humanize` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file.

Comment: I don't see a settings.py file in the GAE project folder. I know I'd have it on a pure Django installation, but for this project I'm not using Django (except to the extent that GAE's templates do). Would I just create a settings.py and add humanize to it as you suggest?

Comment: Finally got it working using a different approach. Original question updated accordingly.

Comment: @mikem great! you should answer your own question and accept it instead of updating the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will do that now!